# html + js: dataset variable being ovewriten after assigning it a value based on src attribute

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

So I have a for loop that iterates over a list of iframes:

```
    var iFr;
    for (var i = 0; i < iFrames.length; i++) {
      iFr = iFrames[i];

      if (isFooBar()) {
        iFr.dataset['sourceBackup'] = iFr.src; //assign src value to data-source-backup
        iFr.removeAttribute('src'); // remove src attribute
      }
    }
```

The weird part is that it seems to remove the src value also from `dataset['sourceBackup']` or `data-source-backup` which I don't understand why. As I'm doing it AFTER assigning it to `dataset['sourceBackup']`.

## UPDATE:

I even tried using object.assign() :

```
 iFr.dataset['sourceBackup'] = Object.assign({}, {'src': iFr.src}).src;
```

Yet still the `iFr.dataset['sourceBackup']` dataset gets erased for some iframes elements but not for others which is confusing.

## Update 2

The problem was with outer code not with the code here. I was having multiple references to the same iframe in different contexts. So this was causing the weird behavior.

Comment: Seems to work for me on Firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/8ukkawkv/

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because both `iFr.dataset['sourceBackup']` and `iFr.src` are pointing to the same object. The assignment does NOT make a copy of the object. Therefore, when you remove the object, it is not available regardless of which reference you use.

To actually clone the object, see this answer: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object#728694)

Comment: sure I also though that so I tried using Object.assign() + Object.freeze() and they still don't work :/

Comment: Please edit your post to show the code using these methods. We'll try to determine why it's not working. However, for the original post, this certainly is what is happening.

Comment: I'm not sure how safe it is to clone DOM elements like this.

Comment: I think its safer that the linked one, since its provided by Ecmascript

Comment: @commonSenseCode: All you're wanting to do is keep a copy of the text value of the source for the iframe, right?

Comment: yeah I just want to copy the value of the iframe.src, without it being affected when this value changes or is removed.